# how to synchronise non-sync branches in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I have two branches `master` and `WIP`. Somehow I have landed in a state where `master` has a change which is not in `WIP` and vice versa.

1. Question 1 - How could I see what are the changes and in which
   branch?
2. Question 2 - How do I synchronize the two branches? I want
   to work on `WIP` and commit only final changes in `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WIP` branch should be in sync with `master`: To achieve that just [rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) `WIP` with `master`, in this way your `WIP` will be in sync with `master` and all the changes you have done in `WIP` will be retained also your `WIP` will be updated

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your questions:-

Question 1:-
If you will go to the branches it will show you the list of commits which you have made, you can select any of your commit and see the changes.

Second way will be by create pull request, while creating the pull request select the base branch as `master`. After creating the pull request it will show you all the change you have made in `WIP` branch.

Question 2:-

You clone your `WIP` branch locally and write `git merge master` by doing this your branch i.e `WIP` will be updated to master. If any conflict is there that has to be resolved.